# Selenium Tests for running less than 1 second

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to do some test maintenance but the tests are no running, Visual studio says it's running for less than 1 second. [[The Error message in the test run summeray at the bottom of visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1CP3.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWOKt.png)

I've double checked the debug setting, I've also tried starting a new instance and running the migrators. It's not just one or two test this is happening with but with all of them so I don't think it's to do with one specific test.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have more than one solution, it works with different people I collected them from many sources:

**#method1. Unable autodetect run settings file:**

The way: select: test from visual studio menu > select: configure run settings > Unselect: autodetect runsettings files
[image: method 1]

**#method2. Check the unit tests files:**
The way: select: test from visual studio menu > select: debug > select: windows > click on output...
[image: method2(1)]

after clicking on output, the output window will appear > click on the arrow next to debug and change it into Text(the last choice)
[image: method2(2)]

**#method3 Ensure the access modifier of the class is "public" instead of "internal":**

The way: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/access-modifiers-in-python-public-private-and-protected

**#method4. Install (MSTest.TestAdapter):**
Install Link: [MSTest.TestAdapter install link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSTest.TestAdapter)

**More methods:**

1. [developers website solution](https://developers.de/2022/03/01/what-to-do-if-your-visual-studio-unitest-stopp-working/)
2. [github discussion about the same issue](https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/issues/1027)